# How do I implement array::max_size()?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, c++11, aggregate

I am building my own `array<T, n>` class template for fun and education. The C++0x standard draft specifies a member function `max_size()` for all containers as `distance(begin(), end())` "for the largest possible container". How do I implement this member function for arrays? Do I simply return `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`, or should the result depend on the element type?

---

Hmm, both `std::array` from current g++ and `boost::array` return `n` from `max_size()`:

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 11> foo;
    std::cout << foo.max_size() << std::endl;   // prints 11

    boost::array<int, 11> bar;
    std::cout << bar.max_size() << std::endl;   // prints 11
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the draft is somewhat lacking here.

It is unclear whether `container` here references:

- any container
- any container of this family
- any container of a given instance of this family

Unlike @Jerry I would lean toward the latter option.

Looking at `basic_string::append`, the description states:

> Throws: `length_error` if `size() + n > max_size()`

With this remark, I think that the Standard puts its foot in the door for the specification of generic algorithms whose behavior would differ based on whether or not the `Container` they are operating on can be expanded or not, which can be checked with `max_size`.

As such, a `Container` should logically returns *its* maximum length.

Therefore, `std::size_t std::array<T,n>::max_size() const { return n; }` is the logical choice.

Note that this same `max_size` definition would logically be applicable to fixed-sized allocators (and notably, stack-based allocators as written by Howard Hinnant).

Comment: The requirements for max_size was written when all containers used an allocator to get its memory. Then max_size() was "the largest value that can reasonably be passed to allocator::allocate()". Without specifying what "reasonably" means.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

If your array is fixed-size, just return the size (`n` in your example), since that is also the maximum size.

Answer (score 4):

It should be `n`, as array implies fixed-size. And here the fixed size is `n`.

If it's anything other than `n`, then what does `n` stand for in `array<T, n>`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it should normally depend on the element size, so you'd typically have something like: `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()/sizeof(T)`. Otherwise, you're giving a size that's typically going to be considerably *larger* than is actually possible.

Edit: Based on table 93, I have to disagree with Nawaz and Jeremiah Willcock. `max_size` is clearly described as the size `for the largest possible container`, *not* the largest size to which a specific container could expand.

Comment: I know this isn't the standard, but http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html claims that "In the case of a fixed-size container, `size() == max_size()`."  The definition of `std::array` doesn't say what `max_size()` returns specifically, but it is probably the same as `size()`.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: it comes down to a question of whether the SGI docs or the standard is more authoritative. At least to me, that choice seems pretty obvious.

Comment: If `array<T, N>::max_size` has to return `array<T, largest_possible_n>::max_size`, wouldn't by that logic `vector<EnormousObject>::max_size` have to be the same as `vector<char>::max_size`? Or, what possible use would it be for me to know that `array<int, 10>::max_size` is something like 1,000,000,000?

Comment: @UncleBens: Yes, `max_size` is almost useless. It's even more so with `array`, because the requirements have never been tailored to fixed-size containers. Perhaps the requirement should change, but I doubt anybody cares enough to bother.

Comment: But still it's just a matter of interpretation. It makes most sense to say that the "largest possible" size for `array<T, N>` is `N`. `N` is part of the type, if it had a different value, then we'd have a different array type? (And implementation seem to agree with this.)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for max_size](http://%20http//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/max_size) says the function should return "the maximum theoretically possible value of n, for which the call allocate(n, 0) could succeed," where n is the number of objects.

The STL containers (e.g. - std::vector, std::map, or std::list) use max_size to calculate container size in terms of object count, not byte count. Therefore, max_size() should not return the number of bytes available on the operating system, but use the number of available bytes to calculate the number of objects the allocator can hold.

If you wrote an allocator class for STL containers, you could implement the max_size() function like this to provide an accurate object count instead of over-estimating by using `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`.

```
size_type max_size() const
{
    const unsigned long long bytesAvailable = GetTotalAvailableMemory();
    const unsigned long long maxPossibleObjects = bytesAvailable / sizeof(value_type);
    return maxPossibleObjects;
}
```

You can implement the GetTotalAvailableMemory() like these functions depending on your operating system. Either will return the number of unallocated bytes which a program's process may use.

```
#if defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)

#include <unistd.h>

unsigned long long GetTotalAvailableMemory()
{
    const long pageCount = sysconf( _SC_PHYS_PAGES );
    const long pageSize = sysconf( _SC_PAGE_SIZE );
    const unsigned long long totalBytes = pageCount * pageSize;
    return totalBytes;
}

#endif

#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN64)

#include <windows.h>

unsigned long long GetTotalAvailableMemory()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
    status.dwLength = sizeof( status );
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx( &status );
    return status.ullAvailVirtual;
}

#endif
```